# saving pdf output from php in IE

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am using tcpdf to generate a pdf file via php, and I am setting the headers accordingly so that when the php file is opened in browser, it displays as a pdf.

Now in another page I have a hyperlink pointing to this php file, and in Firefox, when someone right clicks this link and uses "Save As", the file saves as a pdf document. On IE however, it saves with a php file extension containing garbage value(pdf encoded content). Is there any way for IE to recognize the php as a pdf document?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf')
```

in your output.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the following headers:

```
header("Content-type: application-download");
header("Content-Length: $size");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=MyPDF.pdf");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

Comment: how and where do I add these? my file doesn't exactly have a <head>

Comment: You do not add them in <head>, you write these lines inside your PHP code. Write them under <?php

Comment: If I force application-download, it will always try to download, I need it to open in browser as always while still saving a pdf when using the save-as option